# TFLite tensor android

Tags: tensorflow-lite

I integrated TFLite on android by using TFLite .a static lib. TFLite support TfLiteTensor class, not support Tensor class. How to use tensor on the tensorflow lite like tensorflow tensor operation? For example, tensor ascend dimension, reduction dimension and tensor slice. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

(Copied from https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/47138)

I'm not sure if I get it correctly, but if you want to try if how those ops work in TFLite model, you can make a TF model and convert it to TFLite model. dimensionality manipulation and slice ops can be supported partially with RESHAPE and STRIDED_SLICE ops in TFLite.

Operations on the tensor is actually another op in the computation graph. That being said, the graph would be like

TfLiteTensor -> RESHAPE op -> new TfLiteTensor with new shape.